# ActionMailer::Preview can't read a simple variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Given that my `RewardMailer` has the following preview:

```
class RewardMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  @mailman = 'mailman@mailman.ninja'
  @alice = User.create(email: 'ali@example.com')
  @bob = User.create(email: 'ali@example.com')
  @subject = 'I Vooshed my website'
  @btc_address = '1BitcoinKKKKKKKK'
  @amount = 0.004

  # Preview this email at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/reward_mailer/invoice_due
  def invoice_due
    RewardMailer.invoice_due(
      alice: @alice,
      subject: @subject,
      btc_address: @btc_address
    )
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Rails::MailersController#preview
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #13):
 11   @alice = invoice_info[:alice]
 12   @subject = invoice_info[:subject]
 13   mail to: @alice.email, subject: @subject
 14 end
```

my `RewardMailer` has the action:

```
  def invoice_due(invoice_info)
    @btc_address = invoice_info[:btc_address]
    @alice = invoice_info[:alice]
    @subject = invoice_info[:subject]
    mail to: @alice.email, subject: @subject
  end
```

and is tested with:

```
  test 'invoice_due' do
    mail = RewardMailer.invoice_due(
      alice: alice,
      subject: subject,
      btc_address: btc_address
    )
    assert_equal subject, mail.subject
    assert_equal [alice.email], mail.to
    assert_equal [mailman], mail.from
    assert_match btc_address, mail.body.encoded
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `@alice` at a class level, but you're trying to read it from an instance. I suppose you do that to share variable initialization code across different emails? You could do this way:

```
class RewardMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def set_defaults
    @mailman = 'mailman@mailman.ninja'
    @alice = User.create(email: 'ali@example.com')
    @bob = User.create(email: 'ali@example.com')
    @subject = 'I Vooshed my website'
    @btc_address = '1BitcoinKKKKKKKK'
    @amount = 0.004
  end

  def invoice_due
    set_defaults
    RewardMailer.invoice_due(
      alice: @alice,
      subject: @subject,
      btc_address: @btc_address
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Forgive my stupidity but shouldn't @variables declared anywhere be a class variable? You'd be wonderfully helpful if you could link to a resource explaining this! ☺

Comment: @amingilani: no, @variables are instance variables and they are set on whatever is current `self`. If it is in a method, then it will be set when the method is called and `self` is an instance of the class. However if you set @variables in between method bodies (like you do in the question), then this code will run when class is loaded (and `self` is that class itself, not one of its instances).

Comment: @amingilani: @@variables, however, is totally different matter. But you shouldn't use them. :)